# struct.error: integer out of range for 'L' format code

Tags: python, fonts, reportlab

I try to run the followed codes under the system of the FreeNAS. In fact I hope the program could create a PDF file and can show the Chinese in the file.

```
#coding=utf-8
import reportlab.rl_config
reportlab.rl_config.warnOnMissingFontGlyphs = 0
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('song', 'simsun.ttf'))

from reportlab.lib import fonts
fonts.addMapping('song', 0, 0, 'song')
fonts.addMapping('song', 0, 1, 'song')

import copy

from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
stylesheet=getSampleStyleSheet()
normalStyle = copy.deepcopy(stylesheet['Normal'])
normalStyle.fontName ='song'
normalStyle.fontSize = 20
story = []
story.append(Paragraph('<b>你好</b>,中文', normalStyle))
doc = SimpleDocTemplate('hello.pdf')
doc.build(story)
```

Comment: Which specific line caused the problem?

Comment: This is probably better suited for a bug report to reportlab's maintainers than to StackOverflow.

Comment: Please add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):File"true.py",line 27,in <module> doc.build(story)

Comment: Isnot the question be caused by the setting of the font?